# Bootstrap model in php while loop data issue

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with `Bootstrap` Model and `html table` with details button in `while loop`. The current scenario is i just showing data in table with fetched data from database.
Screen shot 
[image]

I just implement Bootstrep model with details button when i click on any button in this list is just showing only first entry of data. For example when i click on third button the model is showing first button entry data.

This is my code

```
   <?php
include_once("..\connection.php");
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    $q = ($_GET['q']);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM propertytable WHERE property_name like '%".$q."%' OR property_desc like '%".$q."%' OR property_type like '%".$q."%' OR property_sub_type like '%".$q."%' OR property_service like '%".$q."%' OR propert_location like '%".$q."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}else
{
    $type = ($_GET['type']);
    $sub_Type = ($_GET['subType']);
    $property_service = ($_GET['propertyService']);
    $property_location = ($_GET['propertyLocation']);
    $start_Prize = ($_GET['startPrize']);
    $end_Prize = ($_GET['endPrize']);
    //echo $property_service; exit;
    include_once("..\connection.php");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM propertytable WHERE property_name like '%".$type."%' OR property_sub_type like '%".$sub_Type."%'";
    if($property_service !="" && $property_service!="Select Property Service")
        $sql.=" AND property_service like '%".$property_service."%'";
    if($property_location!="")
        $sql.=" AND property_location like '%".$property_location."%'";
    if($start_Prize!="" AND $end_Prize!="")
        $sql.= " AND property_prize between '".$start_Prize."' AND '".$end_Prize."' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
echo "<br>";
echo "<div class='container'>";
echo "<table border='0' align='center' cellspacing='10' id='mytable'>";
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td><img src='..\\".$row['image_front']."'  style='width:150px; height:150px;  vertical-align: text-top'></td>
              <td valign='top'><span style='font-weight:bold; margin-top:10cm '>Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_name']."<br /><br />
              <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_desc']."<br /><br />
               <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_type']."<br /><br />
                <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Sub Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_sub_type']."<br /><br />
                <div style='float: right; text-align: right; width: 50%;'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' id='modelbutton'>
                Details
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class='modal fade' id='myModal".$i."'  tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>
                <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                    <div class='modal-content'>
                    <div class='modal-header'>
                        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'> Property Details</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-body'>


                    <div id='myCarousel' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
                    <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
                        <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='0' class='active'></li>
                        <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='1'></li>
                        <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='2'></li>
                      </ol>

                    <div class='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>
                        <div class='item'>
                        <img src='..\\".$row['image_front']."' alt='property_front'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='item'>
                        <img src='..\\".$row['image_side']."'
                        alt='property_side'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='item active'>
                        <img src='..\\".$row['image_back']."'
                        alt='property_back'>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class='left carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' role='button' data-slide='prev'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class='right carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' role='button' data-slide='next'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
                    </a>


                    </div>
                    <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Service:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_name']."<br /><br />
                    <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_size']."<br /><br />
                    <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Location:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['propert_location']."<br />

                    <div class='modal-footer'>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>";
                $i++;
}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Please suggest any way to do this.

Comment: when click on button pass the id of that row and based on the id get the record from databse using ajax and load in model ..

Comment: have you tried with echoing your queries ? find that data are  properly set or not in queries ?

Comment: i don't know how to pass id beacuse i don't have id field in `database`. please give example how to do that.

Comment: yes i try to echo that variable but its shows only first entry of data

Comment: which field is unique in your database table ? because without unique field you can not differentiate rows.

Comment: Your are display in modal pop up?

Comment: Yes i am displaying on model popup

Comment: I just added id field in my table. id field is unique @BhavinV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem in another way.First i put modal outside of while loop. And button  in while loop

php code of modal triggered button.

```
    <?php
include_once("..\connection.php");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM propertytable";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."' data-target='#myModal'>
  Launch demo modal
</button>";
}
```

put modal outside of while loop

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a ajax code run when modal is shown.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url : 'info.php', //Here you will fetch records 
            data :  'id='+ rowid, //Pass $id
            success : function(data){
            $('.modal-body').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
            }
        });
     });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make data target dynamic as well

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' id='modelbutton'>
```

to

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal".$i."' id='modelbutton'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
include_once("..\connection.php");
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    $q = ($_GET['q']);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM propertytable WHERE property_name like '%".$q."%' OR property_desc like '%".$q."%' OR property_type like '%".$q."%' OR property_sub_type like '%".$q."%' OR property_service like '%".$q."%' OR propert_location like '%".$q."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}else
{
    $type = ($_GET['type']);
    $sub_Type = ($_GET['subType']);
    $property_service = ($_GET['propertyService']);
    $property_location = ($_GET['propertyLocation']);
    $start_Prize = ($_GET['startPrize']);
    $end_Prize = ($_GET['endPrize']);
    //echo $property_service; exit;
    include_once("..\connection.php");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM propertytable WHERE property_name like '%".$type."%' OR property_sub_type like '%".$sub_Type."%'";
    if($property_service !="" && $property_service!="Select Property Service")
        $sql.=" AND property_service like '%".$property_service."%'";
    if($property_location!="")
        $sql.=" AND property_location like '%".$property_location."%'";
    if($start_Prize!="" AND $end_Prize!="")
        $sql.= " AND property_prize between '".$start_Prize."' AND '".$end_Prize."' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
echo "<br>";
echo "<div class='container'>";
echo "<table border='0' align='center' cellspacing='10' id='mytable'>";
$i=1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td><img src='..\\".$row['image_front']."'  style='width:150px; height:150px;  vertical-align: text-top'></td>
              <td valign='top'><span style='font-weight:bold; margin-top:10cm '>Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_name']."<br /><br />
              <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_desc']."<br /><br />
               <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_type']."<br /><br />
                <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Sub Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_sub_type']."<br /><br />
                <div style='float: right; text-align: right; width: 50%;'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal".$i."' id='modelbutton'>
                Details
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class='modal fade' id='myModal".$i."'  tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>
                <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                    <div class='modal-content'>
                    <div class='modal-header'>
                        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'> Property Details</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-body'>


                    <div id='myCarousel' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
                    <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
                        <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='0' class='active'></li>
                        <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='1'></li>
                        <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='2'></li>
                      </ol>

                    <div class='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>
                        <div class='item'>
                        <img src='..\\".$row['image_front']."' alt='property_front'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='item'>
                        <img src='..\\".$row['image_side']."'
                        alt='property_side'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='item active'>
                        <img src='..\\".$row['image_back']."'
                        alt='property_back'>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class='left carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' role='button' data-slide='prev'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class='right carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' role='button' data-slide='next'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
                    </a>


                    </div>
                    <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Service:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_name']."<br /><br />
                    <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_size']."<br /><br />
                    <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Location:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['propert_location']."<br />

                    <div class='modal-footer'>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>";
                $i++;
}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

you need to change data-target,hope it will help.

Note: don't use mysqli or mysql, use PDO to avoid sql injections

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop looks like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td><img src='..\\".$row['image_front']."'  style='width:150px; height:150px;  vertical-align: text-top'></td>
              .......
              .......
              .......
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' id='modelbutton'>
                Details
                </button>
              .......
              .......
              .......
                </div>";
                $i++;
}
```

So there are 3 main issue I found here is:

1. You are missing tr tag closing for row in echo statement.
2. Missing td tag closing for second column in echo statement.
3. When you generate dynamic  than data-target attribute of button is not dynamic according to your model.

**So please try this code:**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td><img src='..\\".$row['image_front']."'  style='width:150px; height:150px;  vertical-align: text-top'></td>
              <td valign='top'><span style='font-weight:bold; margin-top:10cm '>Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_name']."<br /><br />
              <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_desc']."<br /><br />
               <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_type']."<br /><br />
                <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Sub Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_sub_type']."<br /><br />
                <div style='float: right; text-align: right; width: 50%;'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal".$i."' id='modelbutton'>
                Details
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class='modal fade' id='myModal".$i."'  tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>
                <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                    <div class='modal-content'>
                    <div class='modal-header'>
                        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'> Property Details</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-body'>


                    <div id='myCarousel' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
                    <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
                        <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='0' class='active'></li>
                        <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='1'></li>
                        <li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='2'></li>
                      </ol>

                    <div class='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>
                        <div class='item'>
                        <img src='..\\".$row['image_front']."' alt='property_front'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='item'>
                        <img src='..\\".$row['image_side']."'
                        alt='property_side'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='item active'>
                        <img src='..\\".$row['image_back']."'
                        alt='property_back'>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class='left carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' role='button' data-slide='prev'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class='right carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' role='button' data-slide='next'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>
                    </a>


                    </div>
                    <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Service:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_name']."<br /><br />
                    <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['property_size']."<br /><br />
                    <span style='font-weight:bold; '>Property Location:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>".$row['propert_location']."<br />

                    <div class='modal-footer'>
                        <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div></td></tr>";
                $i++;
}
```

Hope this works for you...

Comment: Ya i know but only need one row in my case